# Java escaping regex meta characters and constrct

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to form regex pattern from a string containing non meta-characters - `(%, &)` and meta characters - `([, ], {, },|)`.

Question is, I want to(how to) identify any character that is potential meta character of java Pattern and escape it using `"\\"` and then I can replace some of non meta characters with regex meta character `.*` or `.+`
e.g. input string = "%abc&xy[z,p)"
1st step output( where I need help to identify and escape all meta char) - "%abc&xy\\[z,p\\)"
2nd setp output( where I would do custom char replacement(no help needed here)) - ".*abc.+\\[z,p\\)"

p.s. - I don't think `Pattern.quote()` or `Pattern.Literal` is answer here. As of now only option I see is to have map of those meta chars and inspect each character against it.

Comment: Can you give us an example of an unescaped and escaped string?

Comment: I understood request for examples but didn't understand why question was not apparent. anyhow thanks Dirk for the suggestion. That might just work!

Comment: @axiopisty if you think question is still not clear enough let me know otherwise please undo ur did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Java regexp patterns can be found here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html.

You should have a special look at `\Q` and `\E`, which are designed for escaping large portions of text without specially handling all.

If I understand your request right, you want e.g. have e.g. a marker like `MYCODE` to change into `.*`, then the change could be:

- add `\Q` at the beginning
- add `\E` at the end
- replace `MYCODE` with `\E.*\Q`

Didn't test this in Java myself, but it is the same principle as in perl.

So `Match all the {MYCODE open brackets` becomes `\QMatch all the {\E.*\Q open brackets\E`.

You probably need to escape any `\` inside the block. Not sure about this.